# Expectation of uniform random variable knowing sum of $n$ identical uniform variables.

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables on $[0,1]$. Find: $$ \mathbb{E}[X_1|X_1 + ... + X_n = x] $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** for each $k$
 $$ \mathbb{E}[X_1|X_1 + ... + X_n = x]
=  \mathbb{E}[X_k|X_1 + ... + X_n = x] $$

Now what happens if you make the sum?

Comment: Meaning simply the sum of [Xk|X1+...+Xn=x] over all k? Therefore [X1|X1+...+Xn=x] = x/n. I did it a slightly different (and longer way) using Irwin-Hall distributions and got a different answer.

Comment: @user194227 add this to your questio, so i can tell you what is wrong